# Finding a text file in Ubuntu directories

Tags: file, directory

I have this program and my goal is finding the text file programs in linux, but it finds all files like `*.*`.
Could you please help me to find the problem of code?

```cs
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str[256], str2[256], buf[256]; 
    strcpy(str,"find -name ");
    strcpy(str2,"'*.txt'");
    sprintf(buf, "/bin/sh -c %s %s", str,str2);
    system(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` if called without a location to search in, is 'execution location sensitive' meaning if you execute your program from say `/` (root) with `/home/you/myprogram/./executable`, your program will start searching all directories on your system. If you instead are in `/home/you/myprogram`, which for example contained also a textfile called `test.txt` you would find `test.txt` by running `./executable`.

I would suggest either using your program with this behavior in mind, or introducing another parameter to `find`, which specifies the location to search in.
For further information see `man find`.